# Not possible to see always free micro shape

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I would like to create always free micro shape (VM.Standard.E2.1.Micro), but I don't see it in my list of shapes. Do I need to apply for the Always free Tier, to be eligible to use resources in Always free tier or is it automatically assigned to all accounts?

Thank you
Ondrej

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the "AD" (Availability Domain).

In a region with 3 ADs there seems to be only 1 AD eligible (random?) when you want to create the instance for Always Free Tier. So if it is greyed out in "Legacy Shapes", select another AD and try again. If it still isn't working, try the third one :).

Also applicable with the *"Error: 404-NotAuthorizedOrNotFound, shape VM.Standard.E2.1.Micro not found"* when using Terraform.

Answer (score 0):

You can only get access to micro shapes in free tier accounts. So you need to register for a free tier account to be eligible for the always free micro shape.

Comment: I sent a request to Oracle Support, but the answer was: "Kindly note that your free Oracle Cloud account includes the always free account." 
I also received the answer, that "it depends on region and service availability". My region is London. As far as I know, Always Frei Tier is available there. So what does it looks the "Service Availability" is somehow limited to me regarding the comments. 
What does it mean? Thank you.

Comment: You can find the service availability on this page: https://www.oracle.com/cloud/data-regions.html#emea
So UK South (London) should be fine.

Comment: Is London your home region? In free tier you can only create resources in you home region, even if you subscribe to other regions, the resource limit will be 0 there.

Comment: Hello. Sorted out with Oracle Sales. They provided me with a new registration link. Now I can see the always free tier in my dashboard. Thank you for your help.

Comment: No, the paid tier can create free always instances.